# SQL Server AG Listener (tag)

Tags: discussion, tagging

As an example [this question was edited](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/108403/2) and tagged with [listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listener) which refers to the Oracle Listener, not SQL Server.
[image]

In that respect should a tag be created? This may be considered rare cases by some but there are other questions could have this tag added if created (examples [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/124947/507), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68331/507), and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101876/507)).

If so, any preference on naming? [Examples: [ag-listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ag-listener) or [sqlserver-listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver-listener) maybe?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a fan of having tags per product (aside from the top level ones, of course), so [sqlserver-listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver-listener) is a non-starter for me.

There does not appear to be any crucial difference between an Oracle Net Listener, and any other sort of Listener, so it seems unnecessary to create [ag-listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ag-listener), especially since [listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listener) only has 47 questions (21 in the past 12 months).

It would seem better to **edit the existing [listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listener) wiki** and excerpt to be more generic, covering all types of network listener.

There are no [listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listener) questions (except the one mentioned in the question) that are not already tagged [oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle), so no information would be lost. The subject question would then be quite happily tagged as-is:

[sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)[sql-server-2014](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014)[availability-groups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/availability-groups)[listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listener)

---

**Update:** Based on the feedback, I have edited the existing tag excerpt and wiki.